# Can't install python pandas on Windows 10

Tags: python, pandas, windows

The python pandas module used to work when I was on python 3.8. I have upgraded to python 3.9 and it stopped working. I've tried installing it but am getting an error.

This is my python version:

```
Python 3.9.0a1
```

I am trying to install the pandas python module on windows 10. But when I do I get this error:

```
pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.0.4.tar.gz (5.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: still running...
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
pip :   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
At line:1 char:1
```

This is the full error: https://pastebin.com/dEuEkmGE

I do have numpy and cython installed:

### nympy

```
 pip show numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.18.4
Summary: NumPy is the fundamental package for array computing with Python.
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\tdun0002\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

### cython

```
pip show cython
Name: Cython
Version: 0.29.19
Summary: The Cython compiler for writing C extensions for the Python language.
Home-page: http://cython.org/
Author: Robert Bradshaw, Stefan Behnel, Dag Seljebotn, Greg Ewing, et al.
Author-email: cython-devel@python.org
License: Apache
Location: c:\users\tdun0002\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

How do I get past this error?

Comment: Check if you have more than one version of Python in your system.

Comment: How do I check for multiple versions of python under windows?

Comment: Try typing "py -0p" for installed python versions and their paths or "py -h" for more help. Also, you can try installing a package to a specific version "python3 -m pip install ..."

Comment: you want to use python 3.9 right? this link suggests that there has been issues: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32045, but Iam gonna give it a try.

Comment: Using windows8.1, and Python 3.9 (not a dev version), in a new environment , I have the same issues. If you need Python 3.9, you may want to say it in your question.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes I have just upgraded to python 3.9 and have run into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem with python 2.7.13
here is my solution:
1. install Cython with

```
pip install Cython
```

2. install g++ and gcc

```
apt-get install gcc, g++
```

3. uninstall pandas

```
pip uninstall pandas
```

4. reinstall pandas

```
pip install pandas
```

then everything will be OK.

Comment: I already have Cython installed, noted in the OP. Also this is windows so I don't think gcc, g++ comes into play.

Comment: did you try force install?

Comment: It was a problem with python 3.9. I've downgraded to python 3.8 and was able to install.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader.git.
```

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas

Comment: Please update your setup tools using:   pip install --upgrade setuptools

Comment: Trying to help... i am running the latest version of setuptools (47.1.1), pip (20.1.1), and can reproduce the issue USING PYTHON 3.9, which I still don't know if it is a prerequisite. I have installed all dependecies fine (including Numpy 1.18.4). BUT I'AM not clear yet if @bluethndr wants to use python 3.9, which IS NOT a dev  version. Otherwise, not a problem to install pandas. (caps are not yelling just to attract attention on a non answered question which seems to be the issue)

Comment: Thanks. I first ran into the problem when I upgraded to `Python 3.9.0a1`.

Comment: Downgrading from `Python 3.9` to `Python 3.8` works. I am able to install pandas again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happened when I installed `Python 3.9`. I was unable to use Pandas or install it once I did that. Downgrading from `Python 3.9` to `Python 3.8` allowed me to install Pandas again.