# I can't figure out how to install pandas in PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pycharm

I've been struggling to install pandas in PyCharm, either by the terminal or project interpreter.  I've got wheel and Cython and numpy installed already.

I've tried a bunch of different solutions but none of them have seemed to change much and since I'm relatively new to Python and programming in general, I can't make heads or tails of the error.

I've got the following error as it tries to install:

```html
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_clapack_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      flame_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries flame not found in ['/Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
        FOUND:
          extra_compile_args = ['-faltivec', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
          extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
          define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
  
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running install
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      building library "npymath" sources
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu95', 'nag', 'absoft', 'ibm', 'intel', 'gnu', 'g95', 'pg']'
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize NAGFCompiler
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IBMFCompiler
      Could not locate executable xlf90
      Could not locate executable xlf
      customize IntelFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifc
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize PGroupFCompiler
      Could not locate executable pgfortran
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
      C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c'
      clang: _configtest.c
      clang _configtest.o -o _configtest
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d _configtest
      C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64
  
      compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c'
      clang: _configtest.c
      _configtest.c:1:5: warning: incompatible redeclaration of library function 'exp' [-Wincompatible-library-redeclaration]
      int exp (void);
          ^
      _configtest.c:1:5: note: 'exp' is a builtin with type 'double (double)'
      1 warning generated.
      _configtest.c:1:5: warning: incompatible redeclaration of library function 'exp' [-Wincompatible-library-redeclaration]
      int exp (void);
          ^
      _configtest.c:1:5: note: 'exp' is a builtin with type 'double (double)'
      1 warning generated.
      clang _configtest.o -o _configtest
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d _configtest
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
      None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
      building library "npysort" sources
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common' to include_dirs.
      None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h']
      building extension "numpy.core._dummy" sources
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h' to sources.
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/_numpyconfig.h' to sources.
      executing numpy/core/code_generators/generate_numpy_api.py
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h' to sources.
      numpy.core - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/_numpyconfig.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h']
      building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_tests" sources
      building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_umath" sources
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h' to sources.
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/_numpyconfig.h' to sources.
      executing numpy/core/code_generators/generate_numpy_api.py
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h' to sources.
      executing numpy/core/code_generators/generate_ufunc_api.py
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h' to sources.
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath' to include_dirs.
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
        adding 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common' to include_dirs.
      numpy.core - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/funcs.inc', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/simd.inc', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/matmul.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/clip.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common/templ_common.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/_numpyconfig.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h', 'build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h']
      building extension "numpy.core._umath_tests" sources
      building extension "numpy.core._rational_tests" sources
      building extension "numpy.core._struct_ufunc_tests" sources
      building extension "numpy.core._operand_flag_tests" sources
      building extension "numpy.fft._pocketfft_internal" sources
      building extension "numpy.linalg.lapack_lite" sources
        adding 'numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/python_xerbla.c' to sources.
      building extension "numpy.linalg._umath_linalg" sources
        adding 'numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/python_xerbla.c' to sources.
      building extension "numpy.random.mt19937" sources
      building extension "numpy.random.philox" sources
      building extension "numpy.random.pcg64" sources
      building extension "numpy.random.sfc64" sources
      building extension "numpy.random.common" sources
      building extension "numpy.random.bit_generator" sources
      building extension "numpy.random.generator" sources
      building extension "numpy.random.bounded_integers" sources
      building extension "numpy.random.mtrand" sources
      building data_files sources
      build_src: building npy-pkg config files
      running build_py
      copying numpy/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy
      copying build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/__config__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy
      copying build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/distutils/__config__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/distutils
      running build_clib
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler using build_clib
      running build_ext
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
      building 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' extension
      compiling C sources
      C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64
  
      compile options: '-DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
      extra options: '-faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers'
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign_scalar.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/buffer.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/conversion_utils.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/common.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/datetime_strings.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/hashdescr.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/lowlevel_strided_loops.cclang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c
  
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/nditer_constr.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/refcount.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/temp_elide.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/vdot.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clangclang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      : clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_object.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/scalarmath.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/npymath/halffloat.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/common/npy_longdouble.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/common/numpyos.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: /private/var/folders/dk/5tqckd_n59n_nmjv0rt3jzxw0000gn/T/pip-install-u65n05fq/numpy_cb42e487ad904bb9bad770b9bb0bcd6f/numpy/_build_utils/src/apple_sgemv_fix.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o.d -faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers" failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: '/Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/bin/python' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/dk/5tqckd_n59n_nmjv0rt3jzxw0000gn/T/pip-install-u65n05fq/numpy_cb42e487ad904bb9bad770b9bb0bcd6f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/dk/5tqckd_n59n_nmjv0rt3jzxw0000gn/T/pip-install-u65n05fq/numpy_cb42e487ad904bb9bad770b9bb0bcd6f/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/dk/5tqckd_n59n_nmjv0rt3jzxw0000gn/T/pip-record-v3xhyvmh/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/dk/5tqckd_n59n_nmjv0rt3jzxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-462tsvl1/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/dk/5tqckd_n59n_nmjv0rt3jzxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-462tsvl1/overlay/include/site/python3.8/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/1c/b0bc154996617eae877ff267fcf84e55e6c6808dbade0da206f0419dd483/pandas-1.2.1.tar.gz#sha256=5527c5475d955c0bc9689c56865aaa2a7b13c504d6c44f0aadbf57b565af5ebd (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) (requires-python:>=3.7.1). Command errored out with exit status 1: '/Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/bin/python' '/Users/samkrauser/Dropbox/_!SAMS_DOCS!_/Projects/Python/letterboxd-data/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/dk/5tqckd_n59n_nmjv0rt3jzxw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-462tsvl1/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
pip install pandas
```

If that gives out an error, go to:

File > Settings > Python Interpreter and click on the '+' icon. Search for pandas and install it.

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Python Version 3.9.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62182907/cant-install-python-pandas-on-windows-10 Try this

Comment: I'm not on Windows, so I'm not sure this applies

Comment: Try to uninstall Cython and Numpy and reinstall them. Then, try to install Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Also can use

```
pip install pandas
```

at pycharm terminal

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal and try:
`pip install pandas`
OR
`python -m pip install pandas`
For me it shows Error if I use command `pip install pandas` so try.
Thank you

Comment: Please visit the answer by Thomas [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)